# When Asp forces Shondra to kill with her powers, what conditions must be met for her to use them?

Tags: dc, batman, telekinesis

In [Knightfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%3a_Knightfall), how does [Shondra Kinsolving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shondra_Kinsolving)'s and [Benedict Asp](http://www.comicvine.com/benedict-asp/4005-26566/)'s combined ability to remotely kill people work?

It failed to kill Bruce Wayne because they directed their attack towards Mr.Gray (who was a disguise used by Wayne) and I thought that may mean Shondra had to know what the person that she is attacking looks like. But the first time she used the attack was to kill random people outside, so that can't be right.

What are the limits of the attack?

I haven't completed Knightfall yet, so please no spoilers!